Why is there a sudden performance degradation of a model uploaded to Hugging Face and then reloaded?
I was practicing fine-tuning the llama3 model on Kaggle and then uploading the tuned model to Hugging Face.
I didn't end the session after training on the fine-tuning dataset I created. The response wasn't exactly what I expected when I prompted the model, but it seemed somewhat meaningful.
After training: fine_tuned model
logging.set_verbosity(logging.CRITICAL) 

prompt = "Hi. Who is your owner?"
pipe = pipeline(task="text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=100)
result = pipe(prompt)
#result = pipe(f"[INST]{prompt}[/INST]")
print(result[0]['generated_text'])

output:

Hi. Who is your owner? Your owner is a woman. What is her name? Her name is Lee My husband is a man [emotional] I am very happy to be your husband What is your husband's name? His name is Jin I have a daughter She is three years old How old is your daughter? She is four years old What is your daughter's name? Her name is Soo I take care of my daughter and my wife every day What does you do for a living

I uploaded the model to Kaggle, reloaded it, and entered the same prompt, but this time the model responded with a bunch of nonsensical words. What's the problem?
Code for uploading and reloading the model:
model.push_to_hub('sanghyun89/firstFineTunned')
tokenizer.push_to_hub('sanghyun89/firstFineTunned')
load_model = "sanghyun89/firstFineTunned"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(load_model)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(load_model)
# QLoRA config
quant_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch_dtype,
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=False,
)

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    load_model,
    quantization_config=quant_config,
    device_map={"": 0}
)
model.config.use_cache = False
model.config.pretraining_tp = 1

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
              load_model,
              trust_remote_code=True)
tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
tokenizer.padding_side = "right"

prompt = "Hi. Who is your owner?"
pipe = pipeline(task="text-generation", model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, max_length=100)
#result = pipe(prompt)
result = pipe(f"[INST]{prompt}[/INST]")
print(result[0]['generated_text'])

output:

[INST]Hi. Who is your owner?[/INST]VictnumPr1 OCC2Taylor1ove onCloseBoTaylorLuc onCloseTraPDObGTurnumPartnerPartnerWTOrder.SecurityTaylorWTObPrTraElitePTydgra onCloseapp onCloseOrder bozPartner onClosePTPrnum/**
WTWTn bozTra SindnumTaylormothmothEliteurweep bozManchesterObfuelGT onClosePrmothManchester onCloseElite Labour لدي/*
EliteckillTayloroveoveabeiweepPT onClose onCloseEliteElite لديOrderElite

Thank you for reading to the end. I would like to hear from experts.
